# Código para impedir que Google Analytics recabe datos hasta que el usuario interactúe

Tags: javascript, html, google-analytics

Alguien sabría como hacer esto? Por ejemplo, que google analytics no recabe información del usuario hasta que ese haga scroll o click en algún elemento de la página. No creo que el código a insertar sea muy complejo pero he probado algunos en la web y no me han funcionado. Incluiría si es posible la barra de aceptar (aunque esto lo puedo encontrar yo en internet). Recurro aquí como la última solución a mi problema. Muchísimas gracias a todos!

Comment: Esta pregunta es muy amplia. intenta concretar más poniendo codigo que hayas intentado. Un saludo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Por una parte debes cargar el código base de analytics, y crear un tracker con el código de la aplicación, tomado de la consola de google analytics. Esto **no envía datos** aun. Solo descarga (asincronamente) el javascript necesario para enviar la informacion y lo configura.

```
<script>
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

// aqui pones tu propio codigo de tracking
ga('create', 'UA-XXXXX-Y', 'auto');
</script>
```

Luego tienes que preparar los eventos que quieres capturar para enviar el `pageview` (scroll, click + lo que quieras)

```
// creamos que no se puede ejecutar 2 veces (para no repetir el pageview)
// que luego invocaremos desde los manejadores de evento
var sendPageView = function() {
  sendPageView = function() {}; // reescribimos la funcion y evitamos multiples 'pageview'

  // Aqui se envia efectivamente el 'pageview'
  ga('send', 'pageview');
}

// ahora configuramos todos los eventos que queramos.
window.addEventListener('scroll', sendPageView); 
document.body.addEventListener('mousedown', sendPageView, true);
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias. Ok, entonces el primer código es para que cuando alguien entre en mi web se descargue un javascript que es necesario para configurar cuando enviar la información y por un lado hace lo necesario para enviar correcto? Una duda qué es un tracker? El segundo código es para permitir enviar esa configuración del primer código a aAnalitycs siempre y cuando ocurran los eventos es así? Por otra parte, ambos códigos deben de colocarse en el header antes del código de Analytics? Muchísimas gracias de nuevo.

Comment: El primer codigo, descarga las librerias y las configura, el segudo codigo le envia a analytics que la pagina fue visitada por un usuario. correcto.

Comment: Ajá, eso es. Se colocan en el header?

Comment: puedes poner todo en un solo bloque `<script>` al final de la pagina.

Comment: Ok lo voy a intentar a ver que sale... algo más a tener en cuenta?

Comment: deberia ser suficiente

Comment: Vale, creo que ha funcionado! Sos un bocha! (creo que se dice por la Argentina). Al comprobar las cookies del navegador me sale una "_ga" aún nada más cargar la página... esto es una cookie de analytic que configura la librería sólo?

Comment: Santiago, correcto. Asi puede dar seguimiento al usuario mientras navega por tu pagina. Recuerda marcar la respuesta como correcta si crees que soluciono tu problema, no es obligario. Salu2

Comment: Disculpa que insista, no es esta una de las cookie a bloquear antes de que el usuario haga cualquier evento?

Comment: Si quieres evitar la cookie antes que el usuario haga cualquier evento, debes mover el `ga('create', 'UA-XXXXX-Y', 'auto')` justo antes de `ga('send', 'pageview');`.. pero que la cookie este ahi, no significa que este enviando eventos a los servidores de analytics. Asegurate de borrar la cookie antes de hacer la prueba.

Comment: Eres el mejor. Me funciona perfecto, fácil, rápido y me soluciona un problemon. Muchísimas gracias.